# How to pass 'any' in AWS CDK to a bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to apply Deny delete rule to any principal with AWS CDK. Here is my code

```
flowlogBucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
      actions: ["s3:DeleteBucket"],
      principals: [new iam.AccountPrincipal('*')],
      resources:  ["arn:aws:s3:::" + flowlogBucket.bucketName]                          
        }));
```

It does not like '*' and I am getting error Invalid principal in policy (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy;

How do I pass any principal in CDK ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be `new iam.AnyPrincipal()`

examples can be shown here : https://codeburst.io/getting-hands-dirty-with-aws-cdk-async-api-c5e007468497

Comment: Thanks. I figured that part out as you see in my answer. Thanks for the link. Seems good examples of AWS Code

Comment: sure, my pleasure, don't forget to vote for the answer please

Comment: ah sorry just did :)

Answer (score 1):

So correct syntax:

```
flowlogBucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
      actions: ["s3:DeleteBucket"],
      principals: [ new iam.AnyPrincipal],
      resources:  ["arn:aws:s3:::" + flowlogBucket.bucketName]                          
        }));
```

where iam is import iam = require('@aws-cdk/aws-iam');